# What's the props "data", "options" of Bar component is in vue-chartjs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, chart.js

What's the props "data", "options" of Bar component is in vue-chartjs?

BarChart.vue

```
<template>
  <Bar :data="barChartData" :options="chartOptions" responsive />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  ChartData,
} from 'chart.js'
import { toRef } from 'vue';
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend)

defineProps<{
  barChartData: ChartData // seems wrong
}>()

const barChartData = toRef(props, 'barChartData');

// what's the type of this option?
const chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'dollars'
      }
    },
    x: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'industry'
      },
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

package.json

```
      "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^4.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.64.2",
        "vue": "^3.3.4",
        "vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2",
        "vite": "^4.4.5",
        "vue-tsc": "^1.8.5"
      }
```

the charts looks fine but

I had `import { ChartData } from 'vue-chartjs';` vue-tsc yelled about wrong type.

I had `import { ChartOptions } from 'vue-chartjs';` for :options, wrong type too.

I have to say the documents are confusing.

somebody knows? thanks